# Search Form block not displaying in Home Page

Tags: blocks, search

I am using drupal 7.9 with the Bartik theme.
I have configured 'Search Form' block in header area.

It is displayed on all pages, but not in the home page.

Then I customized the page.tpl.php file with the following snippet:

```
if($page['header']['search_form']):
  print render($page['header']['search_form']);
endif;
```

But this doesn't solve my problem.
Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at the block settings to see if it has something like "display on these pages" or "don't display on these pages" checked and if so it's saying to not show it on ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem crop up.  On my site, I have a search_form block in my header. On the block configuration page (admin/structure/block/manage/search/form/configure), someone tried to be helpful and checked every content type under content type restrictions. So the block was showing for all content types, but not on the front page.

Answer (score 0):

Is your front page a panel page?

If it is panel page, do you have the check-box  for "disable drupal blocks regions" checked?

If it is checked, then it will hide all blocks regions

Answer (score 0):

Check for the permissions given to your search form.
You might be enabling from Admin with no access to Anonymous user